# Django compare two querysets and create a list based on these values with additional data added for each item

Tags: django, django-models, query-optimization, django-queryset

I have a UserProfile Model and a Friends Model. I display a list of profiles on a the page in a template and I want to mark whether a UserProfile is a Friend of the current user as each is displayed.

I would ideally like to avoid a nested loop on the template where I have to compare the Friend Queryset with the UserProfile Queryset to see if there is a match.

I have models as such( with additional fields not shown):

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

   user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   friends = models.ManyToManyField("self", through='relationship.Friend', symmetrical= False, related_name= 'friend_to+' )

class Friend(models.Model):

  from_userprofile = models.ForeignKey("profile.UserProfile", 
    related_name='from_profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

  to_userprofile = models.ForeignKey("profile.UserProfile", 
    related_name='to_profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE) 

  status = models.IntegerField(choices=RELATIONSHIP_STATUSES)

  date_connected = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, 
    auto_now_add=True)
```

In the views I first get all the UserProfiles and then the current users Friends like this:

```
  profile_query = UserProfile.objects.all().exclude(Q(user_id=request.user.id)).
  select_related('user')

  current_user_friends = Friend.objects.filter(Q(from_userprofile__user_id=request.user.id)
                                                 & Q(status__exact=1))
```

Now from here I want to efficiently work out which of the Users in the "profile_query" set are also in the "current_user_friends" set and combine this info if possible into one single list or dictionary or Queryset that I can use in the template.

I'd like to loop through and create a new field or value called "isFriend" with either "True" or "False". I'd like to do the heavy work in the views obviously.

I was attempting to pass two querysets into the template context named "profiles" and "user_friends" something like the following which is probably a rubbish way to do it( it has some issues anyway on the "else" side of things):

```
          {% for friend in user_friends %}
            {% if friend.to_userprofile.user_id == profile.user_id %}
                <div>FRIEND</div>
                {% else %}
                 <div>NOT FRIEND</div>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
```

Any help would be appreciated. I'm having trouble visualising how best to use the relationships between these models to do minimal Database queries and get the result I need.

Cheers
Marco

Comment: Umm... I might be wrong,, but wouldn't deleting a friendship also delete the two friends here?

Comment: Because of the "on_delete"? Nah that doesn't seem to happen. I've got the "unfriending" part of this working and it doesn't seem to affect the UserProfile instance or the associated User instance...